# ElasticSearch.net NEST use a Wildcard index in query

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

Hi I'm new to Elastic Search and I'm making some experiments to understand the basics of query through ElasticSearch.net and NEST.
I'm trying to translate a query with this syntax:

```
curl -XGET 'http://myserver.com:9200/myindexes-*/XY/_search/?size=1000&pretty=1' -d '
{
  "query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "filter": [ 
        { "match":  { "LOGTYPE" : "XY" }},
        { "match": { "USER" : "mrossi" }}, 
        { "wildcard": { "DATA": "m.rossi*" }},
        { "match": { "CODE" : "WZ" }},
        { "range": { "timestamp": { "gte": "2015-05-02" }}} 
      ]
    }    
  }
}
'
```

I've found how to build the multiple field query, (thanks to those who posted it) but I still need to understand how to create the Wildcard index in the query.
The team feeding the Elastic Search engine has created an index in the format MyIndexes-YYYYMMDD with an index per each date because each date has millions of rows of data (they are log files). I haven't yet found a way to make a query on more than one index, if it is so simple as writing the wildcard in the index name or if I need to do something different.
If you have any clue, Thank you in advance.

---

Edited after some tests on the answer received: I've tried some tests and even if the call to elastic search seems to be successful reading the results I'm not able to understand if I have a problem in my query or if there are no data.

```
Valid NEST response built from a successful low level call on POST: /myindex-%2A/ml/_search?pretty=true
# Audit trail of this API call:
 - [1] HealthyResponse: Node: http://username:pwd@mydomain.com:9200/ Took: 00:00:00.0580006
# Request:
{"size":1000,"query":{"bool":{"filter":[{"match":{"LOGTYPE":{"query":"XY"}}}]}}}
# Response:
{
  "took" : 31,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 270,
    "successful" : 270,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

The above data is what I can see from the DebugInformation of the response. My uncertainty is connected with how the POST command is built, in fact even if my entity is named XY uppercase in the post appears in lowercase, and also the pretty variable has a value of true instead of 1. the size parameter is set inside the request and not as a variable of the POST as in the sample I posted in the first message.
I've simplified the filters to set just one filter and also in the request data I see that in my sample the "XY" filter has a query: instead of nothing as it is in the sample.
so at the moment the query seems to be sintactically correct but I don't know if it is correct on my index data.
can you suggest how to try and use something like select top 100 * from my table just to see if I can find the data, and then try and implement filters???
thank you again

Answer (score 2):

You can use a wildcard in the Index name portion of your query.

```
var client = new ElasticClient();

client.Search<MyObject>(s=>s
     .Index("myindexes-*")
     ...
)
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but the star character is encoded as %2A, maybe it works because the response says that the request is ok but I have no data returned and I'm not able to understand if it is due to my filters or due to the fact it does not find the correct index. I'll try some more tests and let you know thanks for the answer anyway

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the wildcard in the index... is your query not working?